# Custom Vibrations in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, vibration

I've been looking around the web trying to see if anyone has been able to do custom vibration timing. I found information on iOS5 but it was only doable with non app store approved methods.

Is there any API's in iOS7 that will let me do this?

Comment: I don't think it's exactly accurate that this question is a duplicate.  This question was scoped to new APIs in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no new iOS 7 APIs for this.  The private APIs you mentioned remain the only option.

Comment: That's unfortunate. So many interesting effects could have been achieved, especially with games.